# CMake add_executable() use .cpp file or .hpp file?

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I've read a bunch questions on this site about the usage of `add_executable` function in `CMake`, but have not found an exact answer to my confusion.

My question is why we only add `.cpp` files in the `add_executable` function but not `.hpp` files?

I understand header files are like "indices" for functions and classes in the corresponding `.cpp` files. But if we don't include them in the `add_executable` function, how are they used in the build process?

For example, will the `A.hpp` file be used when another source file import `A.hpp`? But then `A.hpp` is not in the `add_executable` function... How does the program know where to find `A.hpp`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Header files, which *often* have .h or .hpp extension, although not always - for example, C++ standard library headers have no extensions - are "copy-pasted" by compiler into every .cpp (or .C, or .cc) which has `#include` directive to include the file.

Because of that, build system, such as CMake, doesn't have to know about them when the final executable is built - their contents is already accounted for by literal inclusion of their code into .cpp file.

However, build systems need to know about those files when dependencies are specified - to ensure that the whole application is rebuilt whenever any of those files is updated, and also to provide the proper inclusion path to the compilation command.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Does this mean it's not the build system's job to figure out the `#include` path for the `.hpp` files? As that's the job of the compiler?

Comment: @yuqli CMake figures out include paths by means of 'target_link_library' for headers provided by app or libraries it uses, and compiler uses predefined default paths for everything else. But that has nothing to do with executable building, so that's why `add_executable` doesn't have it.